What is the difference between "我不太喜欢他" “我不喜欢他” and "我不怎么喜欢他"?
What is the difference between "我不太喜欢他" “我不喜欢他” and "我不怎么喜欢他"? Which one should we use? If so, when can we use it correctly?

The level of “liking” goes as follows:
"我不怎么喜欢他" ≈ "我不太喜欢他" > "我不喜欢他".
On the other hand, the degree of “dislike” goes in the reverse order:
"我不喜欢他" > "我不太喜欢他" ≈ "我不怎么喜欢他".
If we replace “liking” with “socializing,” it would become:
"我不喜欢去社交" (I don’t like socializing), "我不怎么去社交" (I don’t really socialize), "我不太会去社交" (I rarely socialize).
Degree of extroversion in this case:
"我不怎么去社交" > "我不太会去社交" > "我不喜欢去社交".
In most contexts, “不怎么” (not really) and “不太” (not quite) convey a mild, less frequent, or low level of something and can often be used interchangeably.
In everyday situations, you could use any of these, depending on your tone. If you prefer direct language, go with “我不喜欢.” For a softer tone, use “我不太” or “我不怎么.”

In addition to 不怎么, there is another expression that is 不那么/没那么. See the film name 《他其实没那么喜欢你》/ He's Just Not That Into You.

假如：喜欢是100%，不喜欢是0%
“我喜欢他”，喜欢度用100%表示。
"我不太喜欢他" 和 "我不怎么喜欢他"? 是一个意思，都表示我不是特别喜欢他，这里可以用60%或70%来表示喜欢的程度用以辅助理解。
“我不喜欢他”，意思就是我对他没有一点好感，喜欢度用0%表示。
